# Очередность событий Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть блок `<div><div></div><span></span></div>`
При клике на родительских блок <div> вызывается событие onclick, необходимо, чтобы при клике на элемент span это событие не вызывалось, как сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.parent').on('click', function () {
        console.log('click');
    });
    $('.not-bubble').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

<div class="parent">
    Родитель
    <div>
        Ловить
    </div>
    <span class="not-bubble">
        Не ловить
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает, но если в блоке not-bubble имеется контейнер .btn-group от bootstrap, то он не отображается

Comment: $('#ChatWindow .btn-group .settings').on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target!=this) { e.stopPropagation(); } 
    });

Или я не прав? если клик вне .setting то e.stopPropagation();

Comment: return в обработчике, чтобы не делал ничего. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Cvva2/

Comment: @eicto ваш вариант работает не корректно, блок "ловить" тоже не файрит клик, как и любой другой в составе .parent.

Comment: @IOleg вы можете выбрать любое удобное вам имя для класса

Comment: @Ridzhi в чем некорректность ? скажем propagation надо, а вот обработку конкретно эту не надо в propagation, вы же весь propogation запрещаете. есть конечно вариант...

Comment: @Ridzhi http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Cvva2/1/ смотрите этот фиддл с пояснениями

Comment: не знаю..но у меня не срабатывает http://jsfiddle.net/huEZz/

Comment: @eicto Наверное мы с вами по разному поняли задачу ТС. Лично я понял, что есть родительсктий блок, в нем есть разные чайлды. Нужно сделать так чтобы некоторые чайлды не вызывали событие клик, для родителя. В моем понимании, это означает завести специальных класс для которого прописать запрет всплытия события и в дальнейшем просто добавлять этот класс на необходимые элементы. Мне кажется ваш вариант решает задачу, вылавливания клика ТОЛЬКО по родителю и вроде как это не то, что нужно ТС.

Comment: @IOleg У вас мой вариант заработал ?! что не получилось ?

Comment: в моем случае не клик по settings dropdown-toggle останавливает событие клика по всему контейнеру - но при это не отображает блок внутри. т-е блокирует и событие bootstrap

Comment: @Ridzhi можно ещё так делать, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Cvva2/4/
@IOleg, я и говорю, фильтруйте e.target в обработчике событий. кстати - о чем ваш фидл ? это не js, в js так нельзя писать.